# Python socket IPC - port number roulette

Tags: python, sockets

Forgive my total ignorance of all things sockets/networking, this is a relatively new area to me. I am trying to accomplish some Inter Process Communication between two python applications running on the same machine. It seems this is quite simple to do with the `socket` module, and so far I have been able to implement this very well using the following article: [Basic Socket Programming in Python](https://stackabuse.com/basic-socket-programming-in-python/). This allows me to use my local address and specify a port number to communicate between processes. However what happens if another process is already using the same port number? In other words there is no guarantee that the port number I arbitrarily choose isn't already in use, thus breaking my code.

So my question is: is there some way to ensure that I am using a unique port/address combo when serving/connecting a socket? Can I use an address that isn't just the host name? (when I tried this I got a `socket.gaierror`).

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 12345) # what can we do here to use something more unique than the host ip address?
sock.bind(server_address)
```

Comment: If you're doing IPC within a machine, use a Unix domain socket, not a TCP.

Comment: You can let the OS pick an unused port, and then write that to a file that the clients read.

Comment: @Barmar Not a bad idea to hand off the port number via a text file, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way. Is there no way to specify an address instead of just using my IP? Sorry if that is a dumb question. Something like 10.19.9.21/myApplication:12345

Comment: You can only use an address that's assigned to an interface. You can create virtual interfaces in the `127.x.x.x` range. But unless the other server binds to a specific IP, it will reserve the port number on all addresses.